# How are execution conditions and testing procedures traits of an test case for an unit test?

Tags: unit-tests, testcase

[Wikipedia link about what a test case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_case) describes a test case as:

> a specification of the inputs, execution conditions, testing procedure, and expected results that define a single test to be executed to achieve a particular software testing objective, such as to exercise a particular program path or to verify compliance with a specific requirement.

This definition comes from ISO/IEC/IEEE International Standard - Systems and software engineering -- Vocabulary.

**However, my question is how are execution conditions and testing procedures traits of unit tests' test cases?**

I was never taught those terms in relation to test cases for unit testing, which makes things confusing. Maybe I am not understanding the text.

Answer (score 3):

Execution condition is actually the context of your tests (in common terms and in terms of specific frameworks like Spring, etc.). You can control it using so called [Test Doubles](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html) (thanks to [João Farias](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/12740/jo%C3%A3o-farias) since I was not aware of such term) which could be for example [Fakes, Stubs or Mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/346440/8343843).

Execution procedure is simply the logic of your test.

Comment: I would just change "mock" [1] for "test double" [2] - mock is a more specific term | 1 - http://xunitpatterns.com/Mock%20Object.html | 2 - http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html

Comment: Very useful resource! Thanks!

Comment: Google's Testing On The Toilet had [a great article about test doubles](https://testing.googleblog.com/2013/07/testing-on-toilet-know-your-test-doubles.html) and is generally a good source for unit test related wisdoms

Comment: Is the Execution procedure making sure the inputs meet the preconditions and the outputs meet the postconditions? Is that what you mean by the logic of the test? Can you give a simple example if you do not mind? @AlexeyR.